# ruby call method based on record type

Tags: ruby

I have the following methods on my vehicle model like so:

```
class Vehicle < ActiveRecord::Base
  def get_history(start_time, end_time)
    #...
  end

  def gsm_get_history(start_time, end_time)
    #...
  end
end
```

`get_history` is being called all over the codebase, I defined `gsm_get_history` method that's very similar, accepts the same arguments.

how can I keep calling `get_history` without changing every instance of this method call in my code base? and call `gsm_get_history` only if communication channel on the vehicle is `:gsm`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `get_history` to look like this:

```
def get_history(start_time, end_time)
  if communication_channel == :gsm
    return gsm_get_history(start_time, end_time)
  end

  # ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could shortcircuit the get_history method

```
class Vehicle < ActiveRecord::Base
  def get_history(start_time, end_time)
    return gsm_get_history(start_time, end_time) if communication_channel == :gsm
    #...
  end

def gsm_get_history(start_time, end_time)
  #...
  end
end
```